# Weird PHP Behavior

Tags: php

```
<?php
$dog[] = "12";
$dog[] = "3";

for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
  $dig = $dog[i];
  echo $dig;
}
?>
```

`$dig` is always null. Why?

Comment: If you are not seeing any complaints from PHP with this code, then you probably have your error reporting level turned down or have `display_errors` off.  Try adding `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', true);` to the top of your script.

Comment: You would also get a debug E_NOTICE in such cases. It's advisable to enable them with `error_reporting=E_ALL` (in the php.ini) for development setups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`i` is not a variable, use `$i`

If you had [`error_reporting(E_ALL)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on, as you should when in development, you would have caught it immediately (undefined constant).

Answer (score 3):

```
$dig = $dog[i];
```

should be:

```
$dig = $dog[$i];
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy. You want `$dog[$i]`. The PHP engine looks for a constant name `i`, can't find one, so resorts to looking for string. No a key with value `'i'` either, so returns NULL.

Answer (score 2):

your missing the $ in this line

```
 $dig = $dog[i];
```

should be

```
 $dig = $dog[$i];
```

you could also simplify this code by writing it this way

```
<?php
    $dogs[] = "12";
    $dogs[] = "3";

    foreach($dogs as $dog) {
      echo $dog;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
$dig = $dog[$i];
```

You missed the $